# How to locate disappearing Text field in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the following HTML

```
<div role="row" row-index="5" row-id="5" comp-id="213" class="ag-row ag-row-odd ag-row-level-0 ag-row-position-absolute ag-row-selected ag-row-focus ag-row-hover ag-row-inline-editing" style="height: 24px; transform: translateY(120px);  ">
<div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" comp-id="214" col-id="skillCheckbox" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height skill-checkbox ag-cell-value ag-cell-no-focus" style="width: 32px; left: 0px;  "><span><span class="ag-selection-checkbox"><i class="skill-selection icon-checkbox-tick"></i></span></span></div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" comp-id="215" col-id="skill" class="ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-no-focus" style="width: 260px; left: 32px;  "><span><span class="grid-basic-cell">Management</span></span>
</div><div tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" role="gridcell" comp-id="216" col-id="skillLevel" class="ag-cell ag-cell-with-height ag-cell-value ag-cell-focus ag-column-hover ag-cell-inline-editing" style="width: 260px; left: 292px;  "><grid-numeric-cell-editor><input class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"></grid-numeric-cell-editor></div></div>
```

I am able to successfully click on the checkbox as follows:

```
Wait And Click With JQuery         ${AG_GRID_ROW}:contains(${OBJECT_NAME}):not(${AG_GRID_ROW_SELECTED}) .ag-selection-checkbox i:visible
```

How do I enter a value from 0-9 in the input field grid-numeric-cell-editor?

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how you would programmatically set a value in that field?

Comment: What did you already try, and what were the observed results?

Comment: @Don Rowe, Yes I was wondering how to enter a value from 0-9 in that field.

Comment: @A.Kootstra I tried, ```${SKILL_LEVEL_CELL}   .grid-numeric-cell-editor``` then ```Input  text ${SKILL_LEVEL_CELL}   ${SKILL_LEVEL}``` and I got element not found.